# Cannot boot in ubuntu hard ware error after update

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

Hi i cannot boot on ubuntu after update. I can still access windows 10 on grub menu so i know its not grub error. I already tried repairing it using usb stick boot repair method  and reinstalling it same error. Usb stick have no problem installing on other computer so its not corrupted. hard disk is fine as both windows 10 and ubuntu shared the same  hard disk.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59yvx.jpg)

take note I can boot on windows without any problems I'm pretty sure there is no problem with my hardware

boot repair is done using "Recommended repair"
,reinstalling is done still getting same error. I'm typing this on same hardware using windows 10. I have no problem before just after the updates.

Comment: bump I need help:(